# Extract values from a single line string in list format in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

While writing a shell script, how do I extract all values for a particular key in a single line string which is a list of tuples? For instance, my string is:

```
[{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]
```

and the output should be an array containing `value1` and `val1`.

Comment: Please show your effort.  Take a look at `jq`.

Comment: I can't be using jq, I have to use the native Linux commands.

Comment: What's a "native Linux command" for your purposes?  `jq` certainly exists for linux, and it's clearly the right tool for trying to parse json.

Comment: I was trying to look for a pure awk, grep, or sed command since jq requires installation on Ubuntu.

Comment: Why do you want the output to be an array? A shell or awk array or some other array? Can any of the key or value text contain any of the characters `" : , { } [ ] \n`?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be much more fragile than using a real parser, so you will likely find that downloading `jq` could be worth it in the long run, but if you want to use only grep, since you're on Ubuntu you should have GNU grep and could do the following for the string you gave:

```
grep -Po 'key1":"\K[^"]+'
```

which uses `-P` to use Perl-style regular expressions, the `-o` to show only the matching part.  We add the `\K` in the pattern so that everything before it will not be counted as part of the match.

So with your input I do the following:

```
$ printf '[{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"},{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}]' | grep -Po 'key1":"\K[^"]+'
value1
val1
```

Compare this to `jq` which actually understands JSON:

```
jq '[ .[] | .["key1"] ]'
```

Output:

```
[                                                                                                
  "value1",
  "val1"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fragile approach based on a whole bunch of assumptions about what your input contains based on the sample you've shown us:

```
$ awk -F'[":]+' -v k="key1" '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=3) if ($i==k) print $(i+1)}' file
value1
val1
```